# Pass ViewBag value to PartailView MVC

Tags: viewbag

My `ViewBag` value return empty when passing through `PartialView`.

CONTROLLER

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Name()
{
    ViewBag.Name = "Bob";
    return PartialView();
}
```

View for above `Name.cshtml`

```
@{
<p>Name is: @ViewBag.Name </p>
}
```

Parent view `Index.cshtml`

```
@Html.Partial("Name")
```

When render it shows `Name is: (blank)` instead of `Name is: Bob`.  I am still fairly new with MVC. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Fixed codestyle

Answer (score 0):

Please close this thread.  I used @Html.Action("action","controller") and it solved my problem.  Thank you.